# IOS Factory Reset/Overwrite on Non-Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, erase

Is there an API or method that would allow a Factory Reset from Windows?  I have written a windows app and apps for android and blackberry to both Factory Reset and overwrite those phones but IOS seems to be more complicated to erase programmatically.  My company would like this process automated so that as employees turn in their old phones we plug them in and hit a button.

Comment: The normal procedure is not quite as easy as pushing a recessed button with a paperclip, but it's pretty close.  http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-factory-reset-an-iphone/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's not a programmatic way...

Comment: @H2CO3: Neither is hitting the phone with a sledge hammer, but that's just as effective, if you don't mind destruction of the phone as a side-effect.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see, but doesn't OP want to do this from within a Windows application?

Comment: It's just unclear to me what the benefit would be.  You're almost certainly going to have as many steps in the programmatic way.  It might actually take longer, because you would have to establish a sync connection first.

Comment: So the windows application I've written allows you to connect phones via usb, it detects them and you hit the start button on the software to erase them.  Its pretty easy and it takes however long it takes to erase the phone.  Any way to do that with IOS?  Android has ADB, BlackBerry has javaloader, iPhone has iTunes.  Is there an iTunes way of doing this maybe through a dll or something?